# How often does the value w change and how does it change step by step

Tags: matlab, vector

```
function [w]=example3(v)
  w=[0];
   for x =v
    for y=v
     w(x,y)=x+y;
    end
   end
end
```

An example:

```
v=[5 2];
[w]=example3(v)

  0     0     0     0     0
  0     4     0     0     7
  0     0     0     0     0
  0     0     0     0     0
  0     7     0     0    10
```

I have this code and I'm trying to figure out how often does the value change for w. More than that though, I want to , step by step, how the value of w change (maybe just the first few iterations of it).

Comment: Read about the [debugger](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) You can add a breakpoint to where you want to examine value of variables in the workspace before running the function.

Comment: @SardarUsama input: [5,2]                                                                      output: [0 0 0 0 0; 0 4 0 0 7; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 7 0 0 10]

Comment: I agree with @mikkola, you can figure this out yourself, just set a break point in the line `w(x,y)=x+y` and check manually or display `x, y, w `. This way you also see each iteration. You will understand very fast what is happening. As long as you understand how `x` and `y`are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by others, you can define a break point where you assign a value to w and see its value.
If you want to do it programmatically, you could add this:

```
function [w]=example3(v)
    w=[0];
    idx = 0;  % Count number of cycles
    for x =v
        for y=v
            w(x,y)=x+y;
            idx = idx + 1;
            if idx < 6  % Only display first 5 values
                disp(['x: ' num2str(x) ' - y: '  ...
                        num2str(y) ' - w: '  num2str(w(x,y))])
            end
        end
    end
end
```